# Why is there an error in one case and not in the other?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

Why does the error occur for P[34, 14] whereas for P[33, 14] has no error? How to get rid of this error?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n *Exp[-1/2 *r^2] *Sqrt[2 *n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]]* 
   LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2];

P[n1_, n2_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Psi[r, n2]*4.915/r*Exp[-r*1.65]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 
    0, \[Infinity]}];

P[33, 14]

Out[1008]= -0.500849

P[34, 14]

During evaluation of In[1009]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {6.42115}. NIntegrate obtained 0.488132829059508` and 9.895807414830366`*^-7 for the integral and error estimates.

Out[1009]= 0.488133
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors when I run your code. `v12` on a mac

Comment: @bmf, my version: "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)". Try to run P[41,63]

Comment: see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpDKa.png) for the value you quoted in the comment. Perhaps you should add the details of the operational system and the verion in the main question

Comment: @bmf, strange situation

Comment: @user293787, could you please take a look at this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277927/%d0%a1an-this-integral-be-solved-exactly-using-integrate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP is trying to numerically evaluate highly oscillating integrals. In this case, one can do the integration exactly, using high precision only at the end to add terms:

```
f0[a_,n_]=Integrate[r^n*Exp[-r^2]*Exp[-a*r],{r,0,Infinity},Assumptions->{a>0,n>0}];
f[a_,n_]:=f[a,n]=N[f0[a,n],100 (* increase if necessary *)];

coeff[n_]:=(-1)^n*Sqrt[2*n!/Gamma[n+3/2]];

Px[n1_,n2_]:=Px[n1,n2]=If[n1>n2,Px[n2,n1],
  coeff[n1]*coeff[n2]*4915/1000*Total[Map[f[165/100,#[[1,1]]+1]*#[[2]]&,
  CoefficientRules[LaguerreL[n1,1/2,r^2]*LaguerreL[n2,1/2,r^2],r]]]//N];
```

It is also quite fast:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Px[n1,n2],{n1,0,50},{n2,0,50}];]
(* about 3 seconds *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please describe this part in more detail, it's a bit difficult to understand Px[n1_,n2_]:=Px[n1,n2]=If[n1>n2,Px[n2,n1],
  coeff[n1]*coeff[n2]*4915/1000*Total[Map[f[165/100,#[[1,1]]+1]*#[[2]]&,
  CoefficientRules[LaguerreL[n1,1/2,r^2]*LaguerreL[n2,1/2,r^2],r]]]//N];

Comment: The `Px[n1_,n2_]:=Px[n1,n2]=` part is called memoization, see [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#202640595). If you are asking about `Total[Map[f[165/100,#[[1,1]]+1]*#[[2]]&,CoefficientRules[...,r]]]//N` I propose you run the pieces and look at intermediate results, for example `step1 = CoefficientRules[13*r^2-7*r+2,r]` then `step2 = Map[ftemp[165/100,#[[1,1]]+1]*#[[2]]&,step1]` then `step3 = step2/.ftemp->f` then `step4=Total[step3]` then `N[step4]`. If there is a step you do not understand, let me know which step.

Comment: The polynomial `13*r^2-7*r+2` in `step1` is just an example, in the actual code this is replaced by the product of Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: Thanks, this part Exp[-r^2] in f0[a_,n_] is this part Exp[-1/2 *r^2] in Psi[r_, n_]? I don't understand why there is no 0.5

Comment: In your integral there is a factor `Exp[-1/2*r^2]` from `Psi[r,n1]` and another factor `Exp[-1/2*r^2]` from `Psi[r,n2]`, that gives `Exp[-1/2*r^2]*Exp[-1/2*r^2] == Exp[-r^2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much!