# Сan this integral be solved exactly (using Integrate)?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is it possible to solve exactly the following integral?

```
Psi[r_, n_] := (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!] Hypergeometric1F1[
      1 - n, 2, (2 r)/n])/n^2;

Px2[n1_, n2_] = 
 Integrate[
  Psi[r, n2]*(-(1/(3 r))*Exp[-5/2*r])*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, 
   Infinity}]
```

n1, n2 > 0 (n1, n2 = 1, 2, 3, 4 ...)

Comment: Well, the integral evaluates for specific values of `n1` and `n2`. You can imagine a situation that you create tables of data and then you do `FindSequenceFunction` in an effort to find a closed formula in terms of `n1` and then in terms of `n2`. It's like resumming a series roughly speaking

Comment: Why you need exact integral?

Comment: Are n1 and n2 integers?

Comment: @Roman, yes (n1, n2 = 1, 2, 3, 4 ...)

Comment: Maybe you can live with [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) instead of an explicit formula: `Clear[Px2]; Px2[n1_, n2_] := Px2[n1, n2] = Px2[n2, n1] = Integrate[...]` (making use of the n1-n2 symmetry to gain a factor of 2 in speed). In this way you can just make a table of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can adapt the code in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277476/85954):

```
f[a_,n_]=Integrate[r^n*Exp[-a*r],{r,0,Infinity},Assumptions->{a>0,n>0}];

coeff[n_]:=2*Sqrt[n!/(-1+n)!]/n^2;

Px[n1_,n2_]:=Px[n1,n2]=If[n1>n2,Px[n2,n1],
  coeff[n1]*coeff[n2]*(-1/3)*Total[Map[f[5/2+1/n1+1/n2,#[[1,1]]+1]*#[[2]]&,
  CoefficientRules[Hypergeometric1F1[1-n1,2,2*r/n1]*Hypergeometric1F1[1-n2,2,2*r/n2],r]]]];
```

Timing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[Px[n1,n2],{n1,1,50},{n2,1,50}];]
(* about 1.5 seconds *)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, there are now 2 new answers. If you want, you can always change [which answer is accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 8):

Converting  `Hypergeometric1F1` to `LaguerreL` function we have:
$$\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{4 e^{-\left(\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right) r\right)} r \, _1F_1\left(1-\text{n1};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n1}}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(1-\text{n2};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n2}}\right)}{3 \text{n1}^{3/2} \text{n2}^{3/2}} \, dr=\\\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{4 r \exp
   \left(-\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right) r\right) L_{-1+\text{n1}}^1\left(\frac{2 r}{\text{n1}}\right) L_{-1+\text{n2}}^1\left(\frac{2
   r}{\text{n2}}\right)}{3 \text{n1}^{5/2} \text{n2}^{5/2}} \, dr$$
and using formula from [book: Integrals and Series Volume 2,Special Functions- A. Prudnikov 1986 year](https://fedika.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/4_5888601596782183847.pdf) on page **477** formula **6** we have:

$$\int_0^{\infty } r^{\lambda } \exp (-p r) L_m^{\lambda }(b r) L_n^{\lambda }(c r) \, dr=\frac{\left(\Gamma (m+n+\lambda +1) (p-b)^m (p-c)^n\right) \, _2F_1\left(-m,-n;-m-n-\lambda ;\frac{p
   (p-b-c)}{(p-b) (p-c)}\right)}{m! n! p^{m+n+\lambda +1}}$$

Substituting parameters to formula from book:

```
ANSWER=-4/(3*n1^(5/2)*n2^(5/2))*(Gamma[m + n + \[Lambda] + 1]*(p - b)^m*(p - c)^n)/(
       m! n! p^(m + n + \[Lambda] + 1))*
       Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, -m - n - \[Lambda], (
       p*(p - b - c))/((p - b)*(p - c))] /. \[Lambda] -> 1 /. 
       p -> 5/2 + 1/n1 + 1/n2 /. m -> -1 + n1 /. b -> 2/n1 /. 
       n -> -1 + n2 /. c -> 2/n2 // FullSimplify;
```

we have the **Answer**:

$$\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{4 e^{-\left(\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right) r\right)} r \, _1F_1\left(1-\text{n1};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n1}}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(1-\text{n2};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n2}}\right)}{3 \text{n1}^{3/2} \text{n2}^{3/2}} \, dr=-\frac{4 \left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\text{n1}}-\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right)^{-1+\text{n2}}
   \left(\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right)^{-1+\text{n1}} \left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}\right)^{-\text{n1}-\text{n2}} \Gamma
   (\text{n1}+\text{n2}) \, _2F_1\left(1-\text{n1},1-\text{n2};1-\text{n1}-\text{n2};1-\frac{8}{5 (2 \text{n2}+\text{n1} (-2+5 \text{n2}))}-\frac{8}{5 (-2 \text{n2}+\text{n1} (2+5
   \text{n2}))}\right)}{3 \text{n1}^{5/2} \text{n2}^{5/2} \Gamma (\text{n1}) \Gamma (\text{n2})}$$

```
HoldForm[Integrate[-(1/(3 n1^(3/2) n2^(3/2)))
  4 E^-((5/2 + 1/n1 + 1/n2) r) r Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n1, 2, (
 2 r)/n1] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n2, 2, (2 r)/n2], {r, 0, 
Infinity}] == -((4 (5/2 + 1/n1 - 1/n2)^(-1 + n2) (5/2 - 1/n1 + 1/n2)^(-1 + 
  n1) (5/2 + 1/n1 + 1/n2)^(-n1 - n2)
  Gamma[n1 + n2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n1, 1 - n2, 1 - n1 - n2, 
  1 - 8/(5 (2 n2 + n1 (-2 + 5 n2))) - 8/(
  5 (-2 n2 + n1 (2 + 5 n2)))])/(
  3 n1^(5/2) n2^(5/2) Gamma[n1] Gamma[n2]))]
```

**Verification:**

```
ANSWER /. n1 -> 1 /. n2 -> 3

(*-(5776/(279841 Sqrt[3]))*)
```

$$-\frac{5776}{279841 \sqrt{3}}$$

```
Integrate[-(1/(3 n1^(3/2) n2^(3/2)))
  4 E^-((5/2 + 1/n1 + 1/n2) r) r Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n1, 2, (
 2 r)/n1] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n2, 2, (2 r)/n2] /. n1 -> 1 /. 
 n2 -> 3, {r, 0, Infinity}]


(*-(5776/(279841 Sqrt[3]))*)
```

$$-\frac{5776}{279841 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Very nice. It seems that on https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/02/01/0003/ they restricted the arguments of the two Laguerre polynomials to be the same unnecessarily as you have shown the more general formula. I wanted to use the formula in that link until I noticed the restriction.

Answer (score 5):

The answer below uses [`GeneratingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratingFunction.html) to compute the integral in terms of a [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) (a linear recursion formula). Defining a recursive function for the linear recursion one obtains significant speed at large values of `n1` or `n2`.

---

The integrand:

```
Psi[r_, n_] := (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!] Hypergeometric1F1[
      1 - n, 2, (2 r)/n])/n^2;

int = Psi[r, n2]*(-(1/(3 r))*Exp[-5/2*r])*Psi[r, n1]*r^2 // 
  FullSimplify
```

$$-\frac{4 r \, _1F_1\left(1-\text{n1};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n1}}\right) \, _1F_1\left(1-\text{n2};2;\frac{2 r}{\text{n2}}\right) e^{-\left(r \left(\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}+\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)}}{3 \text{n1}^{3/2} \text{n2}^{3/2}}$$

---

We can compute the integral using [`GeneratingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratingFunction.html)

First notice :

```
GeneratingFunction[Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n, 2, x], n, 
  u] // FunctionExpand
```

$$-\frac{e^x \left(e^{\frac{x}{u-1}}-1\right)}{x}$$

We can then replace $n$ with $n1$ and $x$ with $2r/(n1)$ in the first product and a similar replacement in the second product.

We apply a generating function for each factor and obtain a function of `u1` and `u2`. After applying `Simplify`the generating function of the integrand is:

```
-((E^((-(5/2) + 1/n1 + 1/n2) r) (-1 + E^(-((2 r)/(n1 - n1 u1)))) (-1 +
     E^(-((2 r)/(n2 - n2 u2)))))/(3 Sqrt[n1] Sqrt[n2] r))
```

$$-\frac{e^{r \left(\frac{1}{\text{n1}}+\frac{1}{\text{n2}}-\frac{5}{2}\right)} \left(e^{-\frac{2 r}{\text{n1}-\text{n1} \text{u1}}}-1\right) \left(e^{-\frac{2 r}{\text{n2}-\text{n2} \text{u2}}}-1\right)}{3 \sqrt{\text{n1}} \sqrt{\text{n2}} r}$$

Assuming all the hypothesis are satisfied, the integral of the generating function is the generating function of the integral. We use this to revert back to the series coefficients after integrating:

```
(
Integrate[-((E^((-(5/2)+1/n1+1/n2) r) (-1+E^(-((2 r)/(n1-n1 u1)))) (-1+E^(-((2 r)/(n2-n2 u2)))))/(3 Sqrt[n1] Sqrt[n2] r)),{r,0,Infinity},GenerateConditions->False]

//SeriesCoefficient[#,{u2,0,n2}]&
//Refine[#,n2>0]&
//SeriesCoefficient[#,{u1,0,n1}]&
//Refine[#,n1>0]&
)
```

**Important note** : `//Refine[#,n>0]&` eliminates the case `n=0`. Consider checking separately the cases `n1=0` and `n2=0`

The result is :

[image]

**Verification:**

```
Integrate[int /. n1 -> 1 /. n2 -> 3, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

$$-\frac{5776}{279841 \sqrt{3}}$$

[image]

$$-\frac{5776}{279841 \sqrt{3}}$$

---

#### Speeding up the computation

The [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) in the result should be reasonably quick but one might do better by extracting the recurrence formula from the `DifferenceRoot` using something like `diffroot[[0,1]][y,x][[1]]` and defining a recursive function with memoization. This is what is  done below :

```
(* recurrence formula with y1=y[n-1] and y2=y[n-2] obtained 
 using Solve on the recurrence formula*)
g[n_, n1_, n2_, y1_, 
  y2_] := (n1^2 (-4 + 25 n2^2) (2 (-1 + n) y1 - (-2 + n) y2) - 
    4 n2^2 (2 (-1 + n) y1 + (-2 + n) y2) + 
    4 n1 n2^2 (4 y1 + 5 (-2 + n) y2))/(n (2 n2 + 
      n1 (-2 + 5 n2)) (2 n2 + n1 (2 + 5 n2)))


(* Optional compilation *)
gcompile = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer}, {y1, \
_Real}, {y2, _Real}}, Evaluate[g[n, n1, n2, y1, y2]]];

Clear[recurrence];
recurrence[0, OrderlessPatternSequence[n1_, n2_]] := 
  recurrence[0, n1, n2] = ((-2 n1 + 2 n2 + 5 n1 n2)/(
    2 n1 + 2 n2 + 5 n1 n2))^n2;
recurrence[1, OrderlessPatternSequence[n1_, n2_]] := 
  recurrence[1, n1, n2] = (
   16 n1 n2^2 recurrence[0, n1, n2])/(-4 n1^2 + 4 n2^2 + 20 n1 n2^2 + 
    25 n1^2 n2^2);
recurrence[n_, OrderlessPatternSequence[n1_, n2_]] :=
  recurrence[n, n1, n2] = 
   g[n, n1, n2, recurrence[n - 1, n1, n2], 
    recurrence[n - 2, n1, n2]];
Clear[MemP];
MemP[n1_, n2_] := 
 MemP[n1, n2] = 
  If[n1 > n2, 
   MemP[n2, n1], -(N@recurrence[n1, n1, n2]/(3 Sqrt[n1] n2^(3/2)))]
```

**Benchmark**

Without compilation:

```
Table[MemP[i, j], {i, 50}, {j, 50}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.657429, Null} *)
```

Increasing the maximum range of `n1` to 200 and using compilation by switching `g` to `gcompile` in the function `recurrence` above (the output from `MemP` can be floating points) :

```
Table[MemP[i, j], {i, 200}, {j, 50}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.04846, Null} *)
```

I recall that **one should check separately the cases `n1=0` and `n2=0`**.