# Inverting `GeneratingFunction` of matrix sequence $M^0,M^1,M^2,\ldots$?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Is there an automatic way to invert `GeneratingFunction` of a sequence of matrix powers $M^0,M^1,\ldots$? IE, in code below, obtain `timeDomain` from `freqDomain`?

```
ii = IdentityMatrix[2];
dd = -DiagonalMatrix[{1/2, 1/3}];
timeDomain = MatrixPower[ii + dd, t];
freqDomain = GeneratingFunction[timeDomain, t, s]
```

When `dd` is small, $(1+d)^t\approx \exp d t$ and we can do inverse mapping using `InverseLaplace`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ii = IdentityMatrix[2];
dd = -DiagonalMatrix[{1/2, 1/3}];
timeDomain = MatrixExp[t dd];
freqDomain[x_] = GeneratingFunction[MatrixPower[dd, t], t, x];
timeDomain == InverseLaplaceTransform[1/s freqDomain[1/s], s, t]
```

**Edit**
For special case of 1x1 matrices, inversion appears workable by using contour integration:

```
Clear[A,t,inv,pow,freqDomain,timeDomain];
pow[A_,k_]=A^k;
ii=1;
A=-1/5;
timeDomain=pow[ii+A,t];
freqDomain[x_]=GeneratingFunction[timeDomain,t,x];
t=3;
(2I Pi)timeDomain==Integrate[x^(t-1)freqDomain[1/x],{x,1,I,-1,-I,1}] (* True *)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use InverseLaplaceTransform instead of SeriesCoefficient to invert the generating function as in the Properties and Relations section of GeneratingFunction

Comment: @userrandrand because this approach gives an explicit formula for t'th coefficient (if you don't set t)

Comment: SeriesCoefficient also gives an explicit formula if you use a symbolic t. I tested it and it retrieved the original function for generic t after simplifying with t>0 as a condition.

Comment: I used GeneratingFunction and SeriesCoefficient in this answer to retrieve a recurrence formula for an integral : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277989/86543

Comment: also the Properties and Relations section of `GeneratingFunction` also shows that one can obtain an explicit formula using SeriesCoefficient.